# How can I put the numbers of an enumerate in bold?, How can I sort the definitions, theorems, ect by chapters and sections?

Tags: numbering, enumerate

```
\begin{enumerate}

\item hello

\end{enumerate}
```

I want this result

**1**. hello

I mean, in my code the theorems and definitions are sort like (In chapter 1 (section 1.1): Definition 1.1, Theorem 1.2, Example 1.3, ect.) I want to sort them like this: In chapter 1 (section 1.1), Definition 1.1.1, Theorem 1.1.1, definition 1.1.2, example 1.1.1, ect.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This is not a question; it's a pair of unrelated questions.

Comment: On your first question: [LaTeX enumerate - bold item with non-bold text](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/23723). On your second question: [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333)